# Use deployment manager for appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to Appengine. I found a "Development" tool in the Developer Console and configured it to sync my Appengine project files. I utilized the online editing feature to edit an appengine project file through the Development tool. I made changes and committed the code. My local git identified the changes and was able to sync. However I noticed that my appengine was still serving the old files (the changes weren't reflected). Later I found a "Deployment manager" and understood that though I had made changes online in Development tool, I hadn't deployed it.

Can someone help me on how I can use the Deployment Manager to deploy the changes I made online? I went through the Deployment Manager documentation online but it doesn't speak of how to deploy a Appengine project using Deployment manager.

P.S. I know how to deploy from my local desktop using Google Appengine SDK. I am trying to find a way to do it online using Deployment manager.

Comment: have a look at: https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/push-to-deploy

Comment: I don't that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @MathewParet it looks like AppEngine might be properly supported in the deployment manager now: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions